# Compiling ICS source code for specific board + conflict resolution

Tags: android, compiler-construction, android-source

```
build/core/base_rules.mk:166: *** system/core/allwinner_a10_core/adb:
MODULE.HOST.EXECUTABLES.adb already defined by system/core/adb.  Stop.
```

I can understand that there is a conflict between the ICS source code's adb and the adb provided by the actual board is leading to the conflict.

I want to know where and what file i have to change to resolve this conflict,i.e, tell the compiler which adb to use. (more generically which library to use, as i know this is a generic problem)

I wish the compilation process was explained better by google's reference documents!